# Amazon Lex add more than 5 choices or a paging ability of the choices

Tags: amazon-lex

I just want to ask if there's a possibility of having more than 5 choices in the response card for a slot in AWS Lex or a paging ability? I checked out the AWS docs but there's no mention of having more than 5 options or a paging ability.

Here's my dashboard screen:

[image]
Is this even possible?

**Update:**

I had to implement some sort of categorization of the responses and group them accordingly which resulted to the bot to ask multiple questions before giving the final answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are absolutely correct, the array of `buttons` inside `genericAttachments` of response cards has a maximum size of 5.

Source: [AWS documentation.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/API_runtime_GenericAttachment.html)

Detail: 
[image]

Comment: Yeah. So I opted to a multi-tier questions for the bot to produce the final response.

Comment: Good call. And it has happened to me, those limits are very easy to miss :)